# Reading Directory + Creating Shortcuts with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shortcut

everyone. I'm trying to figure out a way to read the contents of a directory in Windows and find files of a specific file extension ('.hod' in this case), then create shortcuts to each of those files into 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop.'

Below is an example I've been testing with so far in PowerShell (I know it looks utterly terrible). I'd appreciate any input. Thanks.

```
$shortcutfiles = dir "C:\C:\IBM-Shortcuts\*.hod"
$DestinationDir = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
foreach ($shortcutfile in $shortcutfiles ) {
$TargetPath = Get-ChildItem "C:\IBMiACS-Shortcuts" -Filter *.hod -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
$BaseName = Get-ChildItem "C:\IBMiACS-Shortcuts" -Filter *.hod -Recurse | % { $_.BaseName }
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$DestinationDir" & "$BaseName"+lnk)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "$TargetPath"
$Shortcut.Save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So a few things to note here:

- Use Full cmdlet names instead of alias', this for clarity.

  - `Get-Childitem` instead of  `dir`
  - `... | Foreach-Object { ...` instead of `... | % ...`
- Only iterate over the folders contents once and reference the `$_` variable within the loop instead of looping within a loop
- if a variable is only being used once then don't bother storing it in its own variable

  - `$Destination` is no longer used
- Indent your code following basic formatting [rules](https://poshcode.gitbook.io/powershell-practice-and-style/style-guide/code-layout-and-formatting)
- As @mklement0 mentioned,  it's worth executing `$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell` only once, before the pipeline.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell

Get-ChildItem "C:\IBM-Shortcuts\*.hod" | Foreach-Object {
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\$($_.BaseName).lnk")
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $_.FullName
    $Shortcut.Save()
}
```

Some other things to note:

- On line 1 you are referencing `"C:\C:\IBM-Shortcuts\*.hod"`, this has one too many `C:\` in it.
- Your use of `$TargetPath = Get-ChildItem "C:\IBMiACS-Shortcuts" -Filter *.hod -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }` is not setting the `targetpath` for the current iteration of `$Shortcutfile`, it is returning a list of all file paths in `"C:\IBMiACS-Shortcuts"`
- Take a look into the basics of a `foreach` loop [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/)

Comment: Thank you, Otter. Code works great. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, to mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.